# Is SharePoint compatible with Office 2010?

Tags: ms-office, sharepoint-2007, office-2010

I have a site developed in Microsoft Office SharePoint server 2007 and I have installed Microsoft office 2010 on my machine. When I try to access excel file stored in document library. It gives me an error saying that it requires a Windows SharePoint Services compatible application.

It was working fine when I have Microsoft office 2007. So I am confused whether SharePoint is compatible with office 2010 or not...?

Thanks

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is compatible and it should work.  A number of things could be going on.

- The OWSSUPP.DLL may not be registered correctly.
  You could register it manually or reinstall
- If you have the 64 bit version of office there are some known issues opening data in SharePoint.
  http://www.knowsharepoint.com/2010/06/sharepoint-datasheet-view-and-office.html
- Windows SharePoint Services Support files may not be installed.
  in this case install these through Add/Remove programs.  It's in the office tools section of the MS Office application.
- If you have some applications that were part of Office 2003 or earlier you may need to uninstall them.